# Call multiple API with NodeJS and merge them together

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm changing the question cause I think I explain myself wrong.

I'm using currently 1 API endpoint to receive data which I need. I need to add a second end point to receive data from both end points in the same time, merge them together and store in Database.

First endpoint -

`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`

Second endpoint - `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=${symbol}`

Here is how I receive Data from first endpoint

```
const getBTCData = async symbol => {
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(symbol, btcusdtdata);
};
```

Im returning 4 parameters from this endpoint

And I need to take one parameter from second endpoint and combine it with parameters from first one.

I need this parameter from second endpoint -  `"quoteVolume": "15.30000000"`

I founded that `Promise.all` can be a solution but I don't understand it properly on how I can return data from 2 api and merge them together in a single object to save in MongoDB.

**FULL CODE**

Small explanation - goal is to take data from both endpoints and store it in MongoDB as well as calculating the average for `quoteVolume` on last 200 days.

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
require('dotenv').config()
"use strict"; // This is ES6 specific. Help's to run code faster(IMPORTANT FOR NOTIFICATION SYSTEM)
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC","AIONBTC"];

//a descriptive name helps your future self and others understand code easier
const getBTCData = async symbol => { 
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(symbol, btcusdtdata);
    //recursive functions are complicated, we can get rid of it here
    //by moving the responsibility to the caller
};

//helper function for an awaitable timeout
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', async() => {
    //expand this function to be responsible for looping the data
    for (let symbol of symbols) {

        await getBTCData(symbol);
        await sleep(8000);
    }
});


const getDateTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
};

const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {
    try {
        const url = 'mongodb://username:password@ip.adress.com:port/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
        
        let dateTime = getDateTime();
        let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = Object.assign({ Name: symbol, Date: dateTime }, BTCdata[0]);
        await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
        const average = await dbo.collection(symbol).aggregate([{
                $addFields: {
                    DateObj: {
                        $regexFindAll: { input: "$Date", regex: "\\d+" }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    DateObj: {
                        $dateFromParts: {
                            year: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 0] } },
                            month: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 1] } },
                            day: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 2] } },
                            hour: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 3] } },
                            minute: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 4] } },
                            second: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: ["$DateObj.match", 5] } },
                            timezone: "Europe/London"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $gte: ["$DateObj", { $subtract: ["$$NOW", 201 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000] }]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    _id: null,
                    "Volume": {
                        "$avg": "$Volume"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).toArray();
        console.log('1 document inserted');

        console.log(BTCdata[0].Volume);
        console.log(average[0].Volume);

        const RealTimeDataVolume = parseInt(BTCdata[0].Volume);

        const HistoricalTimeDataVolume = parseInt(average[0].Volume); // 201 DAYS VOLUME HERE 3286033.4285714286

        const DayTimesRealAverage = RealTimeDataVolume * 48; // 1 DAY REAL TIME DATA HERE  196579344

        const Previous200dVolume = (HistoricalTimeDataVolume - DayTimesRealAverage) / 200;

        const MultiplePrevious200dVolume = Previous200dVolume * 5;

        if (MultiplePrevious200dVolume < DayTimesRealAverage) {
            
            async function main() {

                
                let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                    port: 465,
                    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
                    auth: {
                        user: process.env.DB_USER, // OUR ALARM EMAIL
                        pass: process.env.DB_PASS, // OUR ALARM PASSWORD
                    },
                });

                
                let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                    from: process.env.DB_USER, // sender address
                    to: process.env.DB_RECEIVER, // list of receivers
                    subject: symbol + 'Is UP', // Subject line
                    text: symbol + " IS UP", // plain text body
                });

                console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId, symbol);
                
            }

            main().catch(console.error);
        } else {
            console.log('false');
        }
        console.log(DayTimesRealAverage);
        console.log(MultiplePrevious200dVolume);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
};
```

Comment: You can call the 2nd API the same way you call the first, just change the URL and extract `quoteVolume` from the response.

Comment: You can call in the same way as you calling now. also, you might want to use request-promise or Axios for easy handling stuff. is there any issue if you do the same way?

Comment: @Yos Is that the way to call both API's in the same time? I need some data from one api and some data from another api

Comment: Just copy paste the code which calls klines api and change the url for the 2nd api. I don’t understand what seems to be an issue

Comment: @Yos i updated main question, I'm sorry but i'm still confused with how I can receive data from second API together with first API.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty I edited main question

Comment: @Hexycode you don't need `Promise.all`. Just use `await` the second call to `fetch`, then parse the results.

Comment: @Yos is it possible to see any example?

Comment: You already have an example in your code for the first call. The second is exactly the same, just different URL. I honestly don't understand how you know how to use the scheduling library, perform complicated mongo aggregation but you can't figure out how to make a second API call. Maybe you need to stick to the basics first and try understand how promises work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in the same way.

In response you are getting a son object.

You need to do res["quoteVolume"] to get the data.